# How to check for Pointer Authentication Code (PAC) on macOS?

Tags: macos, cpu, apple-silicon

The `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.features` command will not return any value on any Apple Silicon Macbook, because it is not a feature of the Apple Silicon CPUs.
The `hw.optional.arm.FEAT_FPAC: 0` is having the value 0 by default and the `arm64e` string seems undetectable, despite that the M1 and M2 CPUs support PAC.
So how to check for Pointer Authentication Code (PAC) support on macOS?

Comment: I guess that if you detect an M1/2 then you know you have PA.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Such implementation would instantly fail with the M3 and M4 when they reach they market.

Comment: The M1 chip does implement PAC since it works in a Linux VM. However, it does not in macOS native applications. On the same physical CPU. I asked a more specific question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75186888/how-to-enable-the-arm-pointer-authentication-code-pac-on-macos

Comment: Basic PAC is identified by FEAT_PAuth, which is 1 on the M1. FEAT_FPAC means "PAC with fault". The M1 implements Armv8.5-A. FEAT_FPAC is defined in 8.6 and consequently not available on the M1. So, you have PAC on the M1 but without fault on authentication failure.